# Pivot in SQL Server T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query using Pivot

```
Select *
From  (
         Select Quarters = concat('Quarter',DATEPART(QUARTER,EndDate))
               ,Item     = [Name]
               ,Value    = count(*)
          From  TS
          Group By DATEPART(QUARTER,EndDate),[Name]
        Union All
        Select Quarters
              ,Item
              ,Value = 0
         From ( values ('Quater1')
                      ,('Quater2')
                      ,('Quater3')
                      ,('Quater4')
              ) A(Quarters)
         Cross Join ( Select distinct Item=[Name] from TS)  B
       ) src
Pivot ( sum(Value) for Item in ([Status1],[Status2],[Status3],[Status4]) ) pvt
```

And I need in the select to get data like in this example

```
Quarters    Status1 Status2 Status3 Status4
Quater1      0       0        0     0
Quater2      0       0        0     0
Quater3      0       0        0     0
Quater4      0       0        0     0
```

But the data selecting like this example

```
Quarters    Status1 Status2 Status3 Status4
Quarter1    NULL    1        NULL   1
Quarter3    NULL    NULL     NULL   1
Quarter4    NULL    NULL     NULL   2
Quater1      0       0        0     0
Quater2      0       0        0     0
Quater3      0       0        0     0
Quater4      0       0        0     0
```

Someone have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fixed Typo**  Quater1 vs Quarter1  (missing the R)

```
Select *
 From  (
         Select Quarters = concat('Quarter',DATEPART(QUARTER,EndDate))
               ,Item     = [Name]
               ,Value    = count(*)
          From  TS
          Group By DATEPART(QUARTER,EndDate),[Name]
        Union All
        Select Quarters
              ,Item
              ,Value = 0
         From ( values ('Quarter1')
                      ,('Quarter2')
                      ,('Quarter3')
                      ,('Quarter4')
              ) A(Quarters)
         Cross Join ( Select distinct Item=[Name] from TS)  B
       ) src
 Pivot ( sum(Value) for Item in ([Status1],[Status2],[Status3],[Status4]) ) pvt
```

Comment: Thank you som much is working :). please can i add new Column ) in select (EndDate)  and regrouping by him :)